# Remove CAShapeLayer from super layer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove 7 CAShapeLayers from my superview.

I've added a series of CAShapeLayer to my view through

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

in order to remove them, I looked at how we would proceed with a layer, and came across suggestions to add to an NSMutableArray. I did this through

```
[arrayofLayers addObject:shapeLayer];
```

At the time I wish to remove the layers from view I can see that there are 7 items of CAShapeLayer there. I've tried a variety of different methods to remove, all with no effect (or worse, a crash).

Here are my efforts and the results:

```
for (CAShapeLayer *layer in arrayofLayers) {
    self.view.layer.removeFromSuperlayer; //causes a crash
    layer.removeFromSuperlayer; //no effect
    [arrayofLayers removeObject:layer]; //just removes from the array
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer]; //no effect
    [layer makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]; //not applicable to CAShapelayer
}
```

Comment: the second last one should actually work. Are you sure you add the same layer to the view AND the array?

Comment: The only other thing I do with the array is init with     arrayofLayers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: I don't know what else to check - arrayofLayers contains my CAShapeLayers at that point and as you see I add them to self.view.layer.

Comment: you can try to debug and look at the layers that are in the array and compare that to those in the self.view.layer.sublayers (or whatever that property is called) - see if those layer objects actually match.

Comment: I tried using `[layer removeFromSuperlayer]` and it works.

Comment: So this is interesting. As I add the views I cannot see that they are added to UIView (these are CAShapeLayers). Now I can see them in the simulator; so where could they possibly be being added to? My UIView carries the labels etc. that I've added earlier so....?

Comment: please post more of your code. Maybe the error lies somewhere else

Comment: How can I ensure that the CAShapeLayer is created properly? I can see it when I debug the view (i.e. I can see the shape is drawn) but it looks like I'm drawing on the UIView....can that be possible?